# Communication between 2 windows kernel mode drivers

Tags: windows, driver

Never develop any driver before.

Anyway I'm now writing 2 simple windows kernel mode drivers, and the 2 drivers will be installed onto 2 different devices which connect to 2 different buses(ISA bus / PCI bus), and somehow the 2 drivers need to talk to each other and data exchange is also expected, is there any efficient way to achieve that??

Kernel event might be able to enable the synchronization, but how about the data exchange?

In user mode, pipe/socket might be an option, but in kernel mode, is there a counterpart of named pipe or something? Google said that there's no documented API for kernel mode pipe usage...

I'm not quite familiar with windows driver framework, hope I'm making sense..

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [IRP_MJ_INTERNAL_DEVICE_CONTROL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for communication between kernel-mode components. Driver #1 opens Driver #2 by its name and sends internal IOCTLs with input or/and output data.

Comment: +1.  Note that (if you wish) you can use this mechanism during driver initialization to exchange callback routine addresses and context pointers, and then use the callback routines to communicate.  Kernel drivers are all loaded into the same address space, so it isn't like inter-process communication; driver A really can call directly to a function in driver B, or write directly into a memory buffer that driver B created - you just need to know the address.

Comment: cool! i think this is exactly what i'm looking for. and your comment really helps to clear the mind of a driver rookie like me ! @HarryJohnston

Comment: only one more thing, how can I "open" driver #2 within driver #1? I tried IoGetDeviceObjectPointer and ObReferenceObjectByName and both failed. the first argument asks for the name of the device/driver which is supposed to look like "\\Device\\somedevice" or "\\Driver\\somedriver", I tried WdfDeviceInitAssignName to customize my driver's name but, again, it failed...

Comment: @Sean: IoGetDeviceObjectPointer or ObReferenceObjectByName should work. Take a look at http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=24

Answer (score 1):

@[Harry Johnston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886887/harry-johnston): You do need to be careful about writing to a shared memory location. I presume you were responding with the context of implementing a serial buffer between the two devices (only one device can write, and the other can only read), but it should obviously be added that you should approach shared memory locations between devices with caution, especially if there is going to be frequent writes to that location by both devices and cause undefined behavior or lock-ups from interrupts being serviced seemingly unexpectedly.